# AngularJS - Update a variable of a factory from a controller

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, factory

I am developping a web app with Ionic 1 and AngularJS 1.

In my factory (UserFact) :

```
.factory('UserFact', function() {
var user = [];
return {
    'setUser': function(user) {
        this.user = user;
        console.log('(2) User set: ' + this.user);
        console.log('(3) User id is now: ' + this.user.uid);
    },
    'updateSport': function(sportid, registered) {
        console.log('Update sport: ' + sportid + ' --> ' + registered);
        console.log('(4) For user uid: ' + this.user.uid);
        var ref = firebase.database().ref('users/' + this.user.uid + '/sports/');

        // sync down from server
        var list = [];
        ref.on('value', function(snap) { list = snap.val(); });

        if(registered) {
            list.splice(0, 0, {id: sportid});
        } else {

        }

        ref.set(list);
    }
};
})
```

In my controller :

```
function ($scope, $stateParams, $state, DatabaseFact, UserFact) {

// variables
$scope.sports = [];
$scope.sports = DatabaseFact.getSports();

// functions
$scope.updateSport = UserFact.updateSport;

// execution
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
    if (user) {
        UserFact.setUser(user);
        console.log('(1) Ctrl user uid: ' + user.uid);
    }
});

}
```

According to the console: logs (1), (2) and (3) display a userid form my db but (4) is always undefined...

Any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE:

Manuel, sorry, I think I had missed the point of your question. You are correct, using a factory/service, is the correct way to store the state of your application. From the above, I do not see a reason for your code not work. The user must be getting re-assigned elsewhere for you to be seeing undefined in (4), if you are not seeing the same in (3). For simplicity sake, I removed references to firebase and created a working demo: https://plnkr.co/edit/vaN7ySche8GgRQmZgFsa?p=preview

While the demo may not solve your problem, I hope it illustrates that the factory variable (user) is persisted in memory and usable across multiple factory method calls.

---

ORIGINAL ANSWER (MISSED THE POINT) BELOW:

Update the state change handler to save the user on the controller scope:

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
    if (user) {
        $scope.user = user;
        UserFact.setUser(user);
        console.log('(1) Ctrl user uid: ' + user.uid);
    }
});
```

Then, in the template, invoke the updateSport method, using the user scope variable:

```
updateSport(user, true);
```

or

```
updateSport(user, false);
```

Comment: I think I get your point: storing the user in the $scope and pass it from the template to the controller. But more globally, I was seeing the factories as a sort of classes (I more used to C++ and Java) so what is the point of having variables in a factory if I cannot access it from within a function of this same factory? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks GPicazo for the clarification. I don't understand why but my code still isn't working. I not really familiar with those concepts of Factory/Service but couldn't this be because at the time I instantiate the factory, the user member is empty then my function gets returned with this undefined value for user I is never updated then...

Comment: But you said that outputs (2) and (3) output the correct user information. If that is the case, then user would not be empty.

Comment: Agreed... but unfortunately it doesn't work as we expect it to.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the arguments while calling `updateSport` in controller,

```
$scope.updateSport = UserFact.updateSport(userid,registered);
```

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer Sajeetharan but I thought of that but here is my problem regarding this solution: I use ng-repeat in my view which populate and a list of toggles, each on is bind to a sportid and as state "registered" (true or false) but I don't have access to the userid from my view and I am not sure it is a best practice to have it in the view. What do you think?

Comment: you should be able to access because the variables are getting binded from controller